# Track why my website goes to 500 internal server error

Tags: php, web

I have a website that is working absolutely fine. There is a admin panel for blogs and listings etc.
Everything works great except for around 5 minutes every now and then where I get the 500 error.
I refresh a few times and the website and admin log in is back up and running again.

How do I trace this?

All my sites etc are managed through plesk. I do have RDS access to the server.  I have full access ets as it is a dedicated server.

Comment: check the php error logs ?

Comment: Probably allowed memory exhaust!! Google plesk memory limit!!

Comment: the question got closed but Omi, you were spot on. I adjusted that and everything went back to normal. I agree that my question could have been worded better but I didn't even KNOW there were PHP logs etc. I am a complete novice. I guess I should try and educate myself before asking questions!